# Haskell - Lempel-Ziv 78 Compression - very slow, why?

Tags: haskell, compression

So I've finished my Lempel-Ziv compression/decompression, but compared to C++ its unbelievably slow,
I've tried it on
http://norvig.com/big.txt file, but my program can't process it, while in C++ it took only 1 second. Could any of you Haskell Gurus look at my code and tell me if there are some obvious flaws?

## After adding prepending instead of appending, I managed to reduce the time from 16 seconds to 0.4!

Haskell's laziness is so deceiving, it was printing 'compression finished' almost immediately, but in fact it was the compression that made the program run so slow

```
import System.IO  
import Control.Monad
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Debug.Trace
main = do  
  contents <- readFile "plik.txt"  
  let compressed = reverse $ compress contents Map.empty 1 "" []  
  let decompressed = reverse $ decompress compressed Map.empty 1 ""
  --print $ contents
  print $ length compressed
  print $ length decompressed
  --print $ contents == decompressed
compress :: String -> Map.Map String Int -> Int -> String -> [(Int,Char)]-> [(Int,Char)]
compress (s:x) m i c out = do
    if Map.member (c++[s]) m == False 
        then do 
            if c == ""
                then do
                    let newMap = Map.insert [s] i m
                    compress x newMap (i+1) c ((0,s):out)
                else do
                    let newMap = Map.insert (c++[s]) i m
                    compress x newMap (i+1) "" ((newMap Map.! c, s):out)
        else compress x m i (c++[s]) out
    
compress s m i c out = compress2 out

compress2 ::  [(Int,Char)]-> [(Int,Char)]
compress2 out = trace("COMPRESSION FINISHED") out



decompress :: [(Int,Char)] -> Map.Map Int String -> Int -> String -> String
decompress (s:x) m i out = do
    if fst s ==  0
        then do
            let newMap = Map.insert i [snd s] m
            decompress x newMap (i+1) ((snd s):out)
        else do
            let newMap =  Map.insert i ((m Map.! fst s)++[snd s]) m
            decompress x newMap (i+1) ((snd s):(reverse (newMap Map.! fst s))++out)
    
decompress s m i out = out

decompress2 ::  String -> String
decompress2 out =  trace("DECOMPRESSION FINISHED") out
```

Comment: I notice you are using `String`s right now. Those are linked lists of `Chars`, so not generally a good way to store or manipulate large amounts of text. Have you tried using `ByteString`s or `Text`s? I also see that you're appending to the end of lists quite a bit, which is typically inefficient.

Comment: So what could I do to avoid appending?

Comment: Qndel: use Data.Sequence or Data.DList. Data.DList is faster, but it should be only inspected after you finished building it, or else it's just as slow for appending as lists.

Comment: You could also look into a `ByteString` `Builder`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.6.0/docs/Data-ByteString-Builder.html. I feel like a `DList` might be a bit memory inefficient since it would still be making a very large linked list of characters.

Comment: or you could just prepend rather than append. If you reverse everything, it doesn't matter to the algorithm.

Comment: After modifying decompress by adding some prepending, I got 4 seconds instead of 18, but the program is still unable to process the 500 kb file. 
And a question: When I ran the program for 500 kb file with trace, it was obviously much slower, because it had to write things to the screen - it took like 15 minutes to process the file. When I launched the program without trace, it has been running silently for 30 min and never ended - what could be the case?

Comment: @rampion, with C++ code I got 1 second, with modified haskell code I got 3 seconds, which is quite good! Your suggestion to prepend instead of appending saved my life :)

Comment: @Qndel If removing `trace` changes the performance, it's to do with laziness somehow. By printing stuff out, you force it to be evaluated, possibly sooner than it would have been.

Comment: no, trace doesn't force evaluation :D I learned it the hard way

Answer (score 1):

As others have already said in the comments:

- Avoid using `String`; it uses a lot of RAM and it's quite slow to process. Use `ByteString` (if you're expecting to process raw binary data) or `Text` (if you're expecting Unicode text).
- Don't append to lists. (`String` is also a list — but don't use `String` in the first place.) Prepend if it's easy. If not, use `Data.Sequence`, `Data.Set` or `Data.Map` as appropriate. Or maybe even `Text`, `ByteString` or `Vector`.
- If you see a Haskell program that's really slow *and* uses buckets of RAM even though the input and output files are tiny, you  probably have something somewhere being too lazy.

As an example, I had a program to produce a byte histogram. It took about 20 minutes and consumed 8 GB of RAM. I changed a data constructor to be strict, simply by adding a single `!` to it. Now the program takes a fraction of a second! Laziness can make an absurdly large difference if you get it wrong.

Looking at the code you've posted, that probably covers it all. (I'm not sure exactly what changes you've tried and where you're up to now.)

Comment: changed appending to prepending and it went from 600 seconds to 3 seconds, so I think I'm close to C++ :D